# Haskell cabal compile .js during build

Tags: haskell, cabal, fay, haste

Let's say I'm building a web application with haskell as both server-side and client-side code. During the build phase, I want to compile server-side code with `ghc` and client-side code with some haskell to js transpiler.

The haskell transpiler tools expose an executable that I need to feed with `.hs` files and it will compile to `.js` files. How do I specify in cabal to run external programs during the build phase? I can see, that the `UserHooks` field `buildHook` has the return type `IO()`, so I can theoretically probably use for example shelly library to execute shell code to run the transpiler, but I don't know if this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a post](http://engineering.silk.co/post/82777010096/writing-admin-interfaces-with-fay-using-fay-builder) i wrote about solving the same problem.

It's usually a bad idea to use custom Setup files since there is no way to handle dependencies for it, and unless you install these dependencies first you can't even `sdist`.

I find it works well to have an optional command line option that precompiles code when the webserver starts.

Another option is to have a makefile that compiles both.